# How to enable IBAction once numbers are entered into a UIText Field

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am quite new to a programming and I need a help.

I am trying to build a simple calculator. In nutshell: There are two `UITextField` where the numbers are inserted. There is `IBAction` (buttonCalculate) that performs the calculation + there is another `IBAction` (buttonClear) that clears the data inserted into text fields. Upon starting the application both `IBAction` buttons are disabled. The goal is to enable the `IBAction` (buttonCalculate)  once numbers are inserted. In case the user inserts any other character then numbers a warning message(warrningSign2) needs to appear telling the user that ony numbers are accepted.

Can somebody give a tip / hint how I should proceed?

Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Value: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var field1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var field2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonClear: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonCalculate: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var warrningSign: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var warrningSign2: UITextField!

    func appLoad () {
    buttonClear.isEnabled = false
    buttonClear.backgroundColor = .gray
    if field1.text == "" || field1.text == "" {
        warrningSign.textColor = .red
        butonCalculate.isEnabled = false
        butonCalculate.backgroundColor = .gray}

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    appLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func calculate(_ sender: Any) {
        buttonClear.isEnabled = true
        buttonClear.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 74/255, green: 105/255, blue:187/255, alpha: 1)
        Value.text = String(Float(field1.text!)! + Float(field2.text!)!)
    }

    @IBAction func Clear(_ sender: Any) {
        Value.text = "Value"
        self.field1.text = nil
        self.field2.text = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to have a look at [`UITextFieldDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate) - which will be able to provide you with more information about pre and post state changes to the text field

Comment: Thanks. It took me a while to grasp it but it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make `UITextField`(`field1` and `field2`) `Keyboard` type to `Number Pad` or only acceptable number type.
2. You can catch the characters sent to a `UITextField` control by adding the below line:

   ```
   textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
   ```
3. In `textFieldDidChange` delegate method you can get the text and validate as per your needs.

I would recommend to update the code like below,

```
 @IBAction func calculate(_ sender: Any) {
    calculateAction()
 }

 private func calculateAction() {
    buttonClear.isEnabled = true
    buttonClear.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 74/255, green: 105/255, blue:187/255, alpha: 1)
    Value.text = String(Float(field1.text!)! + Float(field2.text!)!)
  }
```

And then call the `calculateAction()` in `textFieldDidChange()`.